# Camera matching application

Tags: algorithm, 3d, camera, match

I am trying to build a simple camera matching (or match moving) application. The functionality is the same as that in most 3d applications like 3ds Max or Maya. Given an image of a cube and a 3d model of the cube, the user selects points on the image corresponding to each vertex of the model. The application must then generate a camera view that displays the 3d cube model from the same angle as shown in the image.

Can anyone point me in the direction of an algorithm for that?

PS: The camera is calibrated and the camera calibration matrix is available to the program

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try with the algorithm illustrated step-by-step on http://www.offbytwo.net/camera-matching/. The Octave source code is provided, too. 
As a plus, you don't need to start with a cube, but just with any two edges parallel to the x axis and two in the y direction.

Comment: Very insightful link. As a comment, though: Link-answers are sometimes problematic on Stack Overflow. Especially if the remote link goes down or is unavailable later, the gist of this answer is lost.